# JSON, PHP, FLOT and jQUERY

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, flot

Basically I am writing a report script where it pulls data from a database and I want to parse it into a Graph using JSON, jQuery and FLOT.

I have got the data into the JSON and the graph half-generates, but it doesn't populate with the correct data (or any data for that matter).

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var options = {
    legend: {
        show: false,
        margin: 10,
        backgroundOpacity: 0.5
    },
    points: {
        show: true,
        radius: 3
    },
    lines: {
        show: true
    }
};  

var plotarea = $("#plotarea");
plotarea.css("height", "250px");
plotarea.css("width", "500px");

$('button[name="getJSON"]').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'reports.php?r=1', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data){
            $.plot( plotarea , data, options );
        }
    });
});
```

});

Here is the PHP code which is working correctly as far as I know:

```
$r = addslashes($_GET['r']);

            if(!$r){
                die('Incorrect Value for \'r\' was set');
            }                      

            $sqlQuery = mysql_query(sprintf(
                "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_registration`), '%%d-%%m-%%Y') AS `date`, COUNT(1) AS `count`
                FROM `crowdcube_users`
                WHERE `date_registration` BETWEEN %d AND %d
                GROUP BY `date`",
                $startDate,
                $endDate
            ));



            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery)){                                   
                $newData[] = array(
                    'label' => $row['date'],
                    'data'  => array(
                                    $row['date'] => $row['count']
                                )
                    );
            }

            //Encode the array into JSON data
            echo json_encode($newData);
```

Here is the JSON array:

```
[{"label":"25-07-2011","data":{"25-07-2011":"27"}},{"label":"26-07-2011","data":{"26-07-2011":"27"}},{"label":"27-07-2011","data":{"27-07-2011":"9"}},{"label":"28-07-2011","data":{"28-07-2011":"17"}},{"label":"29-07-2011","data":{"29-07-2011":"18"}},{"label":"30-07-2011","data":{"30-07-2011":"13"}},{"label":"31-07-2011","data":{"31-07-2011":"3"}}]
```

And finally this is what I get when I generate the graph:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/tTIqs.png]

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right from the [Flot FAQ](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FAQ.txt): check your data types.   To JSON, `"27"` is not the same as `27`.

> Q: Flot isn't working when I'm using JSON data as source!
>
> A: Actually, Flot loves JSON data, you just got the format wrong.
>   Double check that you're not inputting strings instead of numbers,
>   like [["0", "-2.13"], ["5", "4.3"]]. This is most common mistake, and
>   the error might not show up immediately because Javascript can do some
>   conversion automatically.

Also, your data structure is way different from what Flot expects.  Specifically, a data sequence should be a list of datapoints, each one is a list of coordinates:

```
{data:[[0,-2.13],[5,4.3],.....]}
```

As for timebased data, you have to use Javascript timestamps, that is number of miliseconds from the epoch.  In most cases it's just the Unix timestamp multiplied by 1000

Comment: I just added a typecast, so it is now (int)$row['count'] and it is still the same :/